# Is Doraemon supposed to end in volume 6?

Tags: doraemon

In sixth volume, in last chapter it shows that

> Doraemon goes to the future and didn't come back again. The chapter shows how Nobita trying his best to do anything without Doraemon, he got beaten with Giant and still refuse to call Doraemon. Doraemon find him still fighting Giant and help him to get home. It end with Nobita looking at his desk, where Doraemon come at the first time through his drawer. His drawer become a regular drawer without Doraemon's Time Machine.

This is the picture of that chapter

[image]

With that, it looks like Doraemon is supposed to end at volume 6. But we know that it didn't happen because it still continue and they didn't make an ending for Doraemon.

So, is Doraemon manga series are suppose to end at sixth volume or it just another story from Doraemon?

Comment: Doraemon has no official ending... which chapter or which manga are you referring to?

Comment: @Krazer it's last chapter on volume six, I don't remember the number. Probably more than 100. I've update my post

Comment: you have to realize different countries collect the chapters differently. Some countries combine the regular and Plus series, while other included "The Doraemons" spin-off manga into the total volumes for the manga.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Wikipedia Page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doraemon) said

> The third ending was actually meant to be the official ending due to low TV ratings and the Fujiko Fujio duo being busy with other works, but Doraemon did not leave their minds and restarted in the next month's issue. In 1981, this episode was made into anime (called "[Doraemon Comes Back](http://myanimelist.net/anime/2634/Doraemon%3a_Doraemon_Comes_Back)") and in 1998 this was released as an anime movie.

The third ending there is the one you've said.

Answer (score 2):

Doraemon returns in the next chapter in the next volume.

[image: He returns!]

The regular manga has 45 volumes. The Plus manga has 5.